# How can I see traceroute details in NMAP?

Tags: nmap

I'm using NMAP for Network scan ;

The output does not contain the full traceroute details. Can I view all intermediate routers/hosts using the NMAP GUI?

A simple VPN connection IP traceroute...

[image: LA simple Vpn connection ;]

Thanks your answers...

Comment: Why not just use `traceroute`? (Or `tracert` because you're on windows)

Comment: Because i want see all ip locations ; im sorry ; im beginner... Can it make on linux this ?

Comment: Yeah on linux you would just do `traceroute <remote_ip>` on windows, `tracert <remote_ip>` does the same thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with this command

```
nmap -sn --traceroute <remote_ip>
```

And lookup these:

https://serverfault.com/questions/432017/whats-going-on-with-traceroute

https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/zenmap/share/zenmap/config/scan_profile.usp

http://seclists.org/basics/2011/Mar/19

Comment: Welcome to IT Security! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: "I think that links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer."
I have one command there and that is the point. Links are just for confirm my research. Next time dont use links ? Or not this many ? Thank you for your feedback @ScottPack

Comment: @Raymond It's certainly ok to include links, but it would be helpful (particularly to future users) if you would also include a bit in the body of your answer explaining the command, any why it's helpful in respect to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This output simply means that none of the intermediate hops returned an ICMP TTL-expired message, so Nmap couldn't show any details. This is most likely because it used port 113, which historically is often blocked by ISPs because of [security problems with the Ident protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident_protocol#Security). The closed-port response probably did not come from your intended target, so it wouldn't be a good port to use for traceroute anyway.

To get usable results, you could try a few different things:

- Exclude the port 113 from your scan: nmap --exclude-ports 113
- Do a no-port-scan traceroute of your target: nmap -sn --traceroute

In the next release of Nmap, the [scoring function](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/commit/6680f5648da2e3218f379827e2f03085894207bb#diff-fe3277b00a6c64176c9847465f411eb7) that decides which port is used for timing and traceroute probes will prefer ports other than the commonly-spoofed ports of 25, 113, 135, 139, and 445. It would not help in your case, however, since closed ports are more strongly preferred than open ones, and 113 is the only closed port in the scan.